# PHP:: mySqli does not insert a new line with a variable

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli, tinytext

This line is working perfectly :

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`myTable`(Date,Time,SID) VALUES (1,2,3)");
```

But this not :

```
session_start();
$sessionID=session_id();
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`myTable`(Date,Time,SID) VALUES (1,2,$sessionID)");
```

I have also tried:

```
session_start();
$sessionID=session_id();
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`myTable`(Date,Time,SID) VALUES (1,2,".$sessionID.")");
```

All table rows defined as TINYTEXT.

Comment: Strings should always be between quotation marks. Like this: `$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table (column_1 ,column_2) VALUES ('value', '" . $value2 . "')"); `
Also make sure a variable is effective a variable and not simply a string... mentioned as 2nd value in the query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the variable as a variable to your query ad wrap your values into an "'s, example:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`myTable`(Date,Time,SID) VALUES ('1','2','" . $sessionID . "')");
```

Comment: @Hezi-Gangina what is the return value of your query?

Comment: Thanks man! I solve that out (...see @Jeroen Bellemans comment)

Comment: ...Your answer is accepted (...after you edit it ;--))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jeroen Bellemans and @Florian...

I merge both techniques and it works like a charm ;)

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`myTable`(Date,Time,SID) VALUES ('1','2','".$sessionID."')");
```

Thanks guys!